# DispatcherHelper in Windows Community Toolkit

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, .net-6.0, windows-community-toolkit

I am working on upgrading MVVMLight to Windows Community Toolkit and facing issues with DispatcherHelper. I am unable to find any examples which can show me how to upgrade the functionality relating to DispatcherHelper. Any pointers will be really appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/dispatcherqueueextensions#migrating-from-dispatcherhelper

Comment: FWIW, currently you are having a _"DispatherHelper"_ typo in the question title, and the "Suggested Edit Queue is full"

Comment: Corrected @StefanWuebbe

Comment: @HansPassant I have gone through the above article but it seems not working for me using .net 6. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the Toolkit Extension described above is related to UWP applications. But how to migrate WPF applications using the MVVMLight  DispatcherHelper?

Comment: Can anyone answer this as I am still facing the issue?